# How to change Crystal Reports user interface language

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have an ASP.Net website that uses Crystal Reports, and it works fine. But the lauguage of the website is portuguese, and the Crystal Reports user interface is in english.

Is there any way to tell Crystal Reports to use another language, so the built-in commands, such as print, export and go to page shows in portuguese?

P.S.: I don't care for multi-language reports. All my reports are in portuguese only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had to handle this in any programs that I've written to date, but I did a quick search and it looks like you can set UseBrowserLocal in the web.config file. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227537(v=vs.90).aspx

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I found it also. But I want to have a fixed language, not to depend on the client's browser locale.